# VB.Net Memory Issue

Tags: vb.net

We have an application that has some interesting memory usage issues. When it first opens, the program uses aroun 50-60MB of memory. This stays consistent on 32-bit machines. On 64-bit machines, however, re-activating the form in any way (clicking, dragging, alt-tabbing, etc.) adds around another 50MB to it's memory usage. It repeats this process several times before resetting back to around 45MB, at which point the cycle begins again.

I've done some research and a lot of people have said that VB in general has pretty poor garbage collection, which could be affecting the software in some way. However, I've yet to find a solution. There are no events fired when the application is activated (as shown by 32-bit usage) - the applications is merely sitting awaiting the user's actions.

At load, the system pulls some data into a tree view, but that's the only external connection, and it only re-fires the routine when the user makes a change to something and saves the change.

Has anyone else experienced anything this strange, and if so, does anyone know of what might fix it? It seems strange that it only occurs under x64 systems.

Comment: VB(.Net) doesn't have ANY garbage collection. Its the CLR that has a GC. And it plays no role if you run a VB, C#, F# or whatever app. The GC is always the same.

Comment: Are you using any custom controls as it may be an issue with paint events?

Comment: @John We're using a Janus Grid to display most of the information. I just thought it strange that the 32-bit version is fine, but not the 64-bit version.

Comment: AFAICR there is a bug in memory management in debug builds of VB.Net program. Additionally: is this behaviour actually a problem? The garbage collector only reclaims memory when it thinks there is a shortage of memory. if the system has sufficient memory to function properly, maybe you just shouldn't worry about this behaviour.

Comment: What's the actual problem here?  Sure, a 64-bit app will always use more memory than a 32-bit app.  None of this is an issue as long as the GC collects the garbage and your program doesn't consume gigabytes when it runs long enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the best ways to start looking for what causes the leak is with a profiling tool.

http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/

These guys have a 10 day free trial which is normally enough to figure out the area of the code that is causing your problems.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't sound like a problem at all.  As mentioned in the comments, 64 bit programs will use more memory.  The application doesn't use much memory, and it gets recovered after a while.  VB.net doesn't have "pretty poor garbage collection", it uses the same collector as c#, the CLR's collector.